# 騒がず慌てない translation

Tags: translation

> **最低限のことだけを伝え、不用意に騒がず慌てないことを願い出る堀北。**

This is my rough interpretation: "Horikita, who asked them not to panic without '*being upset carelessly*' (I'm still haven't figured out a more proper words), only told them about the minimum necessary things."

**不用意に騒がず慌てない** part made me confused, since "not to panic + without" sounds odd. That's why I was thinking that maybe **不用意に騒がず** referred to the subject (**堀北**).

I wish you would kindly advise whether my interpretation is correct. Thank you in advance for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ず is the 連用形 or "conjunctive form" of the negating-particle/verb ず。

What this means is that in order to connect a verb ending in ず with another verb or phrase, functioning in much the same way as ～ない → ～なくて, you keep it  ～ず。

> 不用意に騒がず慌てないこと

Here, 騒がず and 慌てない are referring to separate (though I suppose on a practical level contextually related) actions.

In other words,

> 不用意に騒がず慌てないことを願い出る

becomes

> "wish that (someone) does not carelessly get worked up and/or panic."

What you're most likely getting this confused with is the pattern ～ずに, in which に acts to turn the phrase ending in ず into an adverbial which then directly modifies the succeeding verb/phrase. The ず in this example is not functioning in the same way grammatically as ずに。

Comment: Thank you for your kind guidance. I only thought that -ず ending is translated as without, I have just learned something new to improve my knowledge..